# Add Method to Built In Class

Tags: java, inheritance, extends, code-reuse

I am pretty sure this is not doable, but I will go ahead and cross my fingers and ask.

I am trying to add a method to a built in class.  I want this method to be callable by all of the built in class's subclasses.  Specifically:

I have a `JButton`, a `JTextPane`, and other `JComponents`.  I want to be able to pass in a `JDom Element` instead of a `Rectangle` to `setBounds()`.  My current solution is to extend each `JComponent` subclass with the desired methods, but that is a LOT of duplicate code.  Is there a way I can write the following method just one time, and have it callable on all JComponent objects?  Or is it required that I extend each subclass individually, and copy and paste the method below?

```
public void setBounds(Element element) {
    this.setBounds(Integer.parseInt(element.getAttribute(
            "x").toString()), Integer.parseInt(element
            .getAttribute("y").toString()), Integer
            .parseInt(element.getAttribute("width").toString()),
            Integer.parseInt(element.getAttribute("height")
                    .toString()));
}
```

Comment: with inheritance you *won't* have to write too much duplicate code

Comment: @Jigar Joshi the only way i know of is to write duplicate code for every single subclass of JComponent I use. unless i am missing something?

Comment: It's definitely *possible*, but I would *highly* recommend not doing it, as there is almost always is a way you can redesign your code to avoid that need. Is there some reason you can't parse the `Element` to a `Rectangle` and just use that?

Comment: I would suggest this seems like a good *static utility* method. Maybe `public static JComponent setBounds(JComponent comp, Element element)`) and then `import static` and finally call `setBounds(this, element);`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following way of doing it. Write a wrapper for the Element class(called ComponentElement) as follows.

```
class ComponentElement{
   private Element e;
   public ComponentElement(Element e)
   {
      this.e = e;
   }
   public int getX()
   {
      return Integer.parseInt(e.getAttribute("x").toString());
   }
   //similar methods like getY(),getWidth(),getHeight() etc..
}
```

Then wherever you want to set the bounds of a component,

```
ComponentElement e = new ElementWrapper(element)
component.setBounds(e.getX(),e.getY(),e.getWdith(),e.getHeight());
```

This removes most of the boiler-plate code that you will have to repeat(getAttribute/Integer.parseInt etc..).

It doesn't involve static methods. The methods are there where they belong. (The getX method belongs in the ComponentElement class. If you went for a static method, where would you put it? Some "Util" class? How would you name it? What other methods would belong in the same class?)

**Edit:**
Or better yet,

```
class ComponentElement{
   private Element e;
   public ComponentElement(Element e)
   {
      this.e = e;
   }


   Public Rectangle getRectangle()
   {
      return //a rectangle based on the attributes
   }
}
```

and

```
component.setBounds(new ComponentElement(element).getRectangle());
```